# Difference between struct complex (*ptr1)[4] and struct complex *ptr1

Tags: c

What is the difference between the following declarations?

1. `struct complex  *ptr1=(struct complex*)malloc(4*sizeof(struct complex));`
2. `struct complex  (*ptr1)[4]=(struct complex*)malloc(sizeof(struct complex));`

Which is better to use?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: Number 2 is a pointer to an array.  It's confusing, difficult to use, and very rarely useful.  You'll virtually always want number 1.

Comment: In the latter you're reserving too little space: for 1 struct complex, not an array of 4 struct complex + all the things said before.

Comment: In first expression we can access using . operator and in second expression we can access using -> operator as, 1. int i;for(i=0;i<3;i++) {ptr1[i].real;ptr1[i].imag}   2. for(i=0;i<3;i++){ptr1[i]->real;ptr[1]->imag}.How this is done in memory.

Comment: the second one , isn't size wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't a pointer to array of struct be accessed as `(*ptr1)[i].real`, not `ptr1[i]->real`, or is this one of those `a[i]` is `[a]i` things?

Answer (score 0):

Let's clean up those calls a bit, first.  C does not require you to cast the result of `malloc`, and doing so is considered bad practice (C++, on the other hand, *does* require the cast, but you shouldn't be using `malloc` in C++).  Also, you can pass the dereferenced target as the operand to `sizeof`, so the basic form of any `malloc` call looks like

```
T *p = malloc( sizeof *p * N );
```

This allocates enough space for `N` objects of type `T` and assigns the resulting pointer to `p`.  Each element may be accessed using `p[i]`.

So, in the first case, you are doing

```
struct complex *ptr1 = malloc( sizeof *ptr1 * 4 );
```

This sets aside space for 4 objects of type `struct complex`, each of which is accessed as `ptr1[i]`.  That's the simpler case.

```
struct complex (*ptr1)[4] = malloc( sizeof *ptr1 );
```

This sets aside space for 1 object of type `struct complex [4]` (IOW, a 4-element array of `struct complex`) and assigns the resulting pointer to `ptr1`.  Each element would be accessed as either `(*ptr1)[i]` *or* `ptr1[0][i]`.  You'd really only use this form if you were trying to allocate space for a 2-dimensional array of `struct complex`:

```
struct complex (*p)[4] = malloc( sizeof *p * N );
```

This allocates space for `N` 4-element arrays, or more simply an `N`x4 array, of `struct complex`.  Each element would be accessed as `p[i][j]`.